# Merging pdf files using ghostscript: is it possible to pipe the find output to gs?

Tags: find, pipe, arguments, ghostscript

I want merge several pdf files into a single one. Found [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358402/328725) on SO, but there is a problem here. My pdfs are not in the same directory, so essentially I want to do a `find` call and pipe the output to `gs`, something like this:

```
find . -path "*_somedir/*" -name "some.pdf" -print0 | gs ...
```

I have checked the manual pages for `gs` but there is no information for null-terminated arguments, so I am not sure how to pass the arguments from `find` to `gs`. I assume if I skip the -print0 flag it will run the `gs` call after the first argument.

Any ideas? I am of course open to other ways to merge the pdfs but I'd like to avoid installing new packages since this is to be done on a community server.

Comment: Have you tried using `xargs`? Also there are pdf tools packages on various distros that do a great jobs of simply merging pdfs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it, assuming GNU `find(1)` and GNU `xargs(1)`:

```
find /some/dir -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 gs -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -sOUTPUTFILE=out.pdf
```

However, PDFs are complicated beasts.  Expect mixed results from this.